# AJAX working with XML but not with JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, json

I have this json:

```
{
    "nombre" : "luis",
    "raza" : "caniche",
    "cantidad": 3
}
```

And this javascript:

```
$('.more').one('click', cargar);

function cargar(e) {
    $.ajax({ url:'perros.json', success:procesar});
    e.preventDefault();
}

function procesar (data) {
    alert("yeah")
}
```

The problem is that the alert isn't being executed when I call the JSON, but if I do the same with XML, it works!

Any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: Add an `error` callback to the `$.ajax()` options. If the request isn't successful, jQuery will pass an error message as the 3rd argument. What is that message?

Comment: You can try to set the dataType argument to "xml". 
function cargar(e) {
    $.ajax({ url:'perros.xml', success:procesar, dataType:'xml'});
    e.preventDefault();
}